# Wildcard search in Kibana for string text in message field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have the following plain text string in the `message` field in Kibana

message: `Request result. Request: amount=58289.540000, name=Raj, so on.....`

In Kibana in Lucene search when I use `message: "Request Result"` then I get the correct match.

But I want to search using wildcard like `message: "Request Resu*"`. Is this possible without any changes to the logs or to Kibana index?

### Edit:

I thought that "message" is a plain text log, when I search "amount=58289.540000, name=Raj" then I get the result but when I search for "amount=58289.540000, name=R" then I dont get any result. How does Kibana know that this is a partial value?

I guess message is not plain text? How can I know what is the type of the log that I am viewing in Kibana GUI?

Answer (score 16):

[image]

What you're trying to achieve, might not be currently available, but you can try putting `Request Resu` in the query bar (without the "Message:" part and no double-quotes).

- `Request Resu` (without quotes) will return every doc where the message field contains Request or Resu or both.
- `"Request Resu"` (with quotes) will return every doc where the message field contains Request and Resu both in the same order.
- You cannot use wildcards inside of **phrases**.
- The search queries mentioned below (one word) would work as per the requirements:

  - `message:*request*resu*`
  - `message:?request*`
  - `message:?req*`
  - `message:*?resul*`

**NB**: Since Elasticsearch applies the analyzers on your queries, it might look like wildcards are working inside phrases if you place them at the beginning/end of words. — e.g. IN YOUR CASE: message: "Request Resu*" (with quotes) will still return both documents on analyzed data, but. that is not because your wildcard worked as expected, but it is because the analyzer stripped the asterisk when analyzing the query. That query wouldn't find the value "Request Resuxxxxx".

You might wanna go through this [link](https://www.timroes.de/elasticsearch-kibana-queries-in-depth-tutorial) for more details.

Comment: So wildcard is actually useless in this case because with or without wildcard works the same way for plain text search in double quotes?

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details. Please check.

Comment: I thought that `message` field in the log is plain text but may be it is not. I have edited the question

Comment: wokrs flawlessly @anki